# Using Spacebars logic in Meteor not obeying logic

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I've got a template helper that returns the value of a Session, in this case it's returning in the number 1:

```
Template.Student.helpers({
  curWeek: function () {
    return Session.get('CurrentWeek').substr(0, 1);
},
```

My template has a table and I'm trying to print to the table a portion of it depending on the value of the helper function. So I have some logic in the template to print the right portion. But it's not obeying the logic. Even though the value of curWeek returns the value 1, the template runs the logic under {{#if curWeek 2}} as well, so both are in the table. I only want the part under {{#if curWeek 1}} to run, since that's what the value is. Am I not using the logic correctly?

```
<template name="Student">
  {{#modalizeBody}}
  <table class="bordered narrow">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Shift</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
        <th>Level</th>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
  {{#each StudsWk1Master}}
    {{#if curWeek 1}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{FullName}}</td>
        <td>{{RoomWk1}}</td>
        <td>{{calculateAge Bdate}}</td>
        <td>{{Sex}}</td>
        <td>{{Level}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week1.Sunday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week1.Monday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week1.Tuesday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week1.Wednesday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week1.Thursday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week1.Friday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week1.Saturday}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
  {{#each StudsWk1Master}}
    {{#if curWeek 2}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{FullName}}</td>
        <td>{{RoomWk2}}</td>
        <td>{{calculateAge Bdate}}</td>
        <td>{{Sex}}</td>
        <td>{{Level}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week2.Sunday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week2.Monday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week2.Tuesday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week2.Wednesday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week2.Thursday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week2.Friday}}</td>
        <td>{{formatName this.Teachers.Week2.Saturday}}</td>
      </tr>
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
  </tbody>
 </table>
{{/modalizeBody}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your helper isn't testing for equality. You have:

```
{{#if curWeek 1}}
```

But your helper just returns the current week and doesn't expect a parameter.

Just add the parameter to your helper function and then return a boolean:

```
Template.Student.helpers({
  curWeek: function (value) {
    return Session.get('CurrentWeek').substr(0, 1) === value;
},
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Mr. Floyd to my rescue again! Thank you, sir.